# How to use the class from a jar file into a JSP page?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I am getting problem while I am trying to use a class from my jar file.

It is working fine when I am using as a package.

Extra details:

1. I added build path successfully
2. now the jar is available in Referenced Libraries
3. I have imported the package in my JSP file.

While I am trying to run its showing error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /MytestJSP.jsp mathBean
>   cannot be resolved to a type

**Here is my JSP code:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" **import="com.mypackage.Beans.*"**%>
..................
..................
<body>
    <%!static int Objcount = 0;
    double d;%>
    <h1>
        <%
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            ***mathBean m = new mathBean();*** //this class available in my jar
            m.setNumber(Objcount);
            d = m.DoubleNum(Objcount);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Is that the actual spelling of the class name? `mathBean`? Are you sure it's not `MathBean`?

Comment: Yes its mathBean only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got my answer:

to add jar file into build war file, we need to add the jar path into **BildPath->Configure Build Path -> Deplyment Assembly**

This help to add the jar file into final war file.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the jar is included on the WEB-INF/lib directory of your war file.

For that, on Eclipse, go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export, and select the referenced project.

Comment: Thanks Andres. The jar has not getting build along with the war while deploying. please suggest me how can i achieve this?

Comment: i have done this. Even though its not reflecting. still the WEB-INF directory not filled with lib/myjar.jar :(